Trying to hide/show content in wordpress page based on custom fields
Hey guys I'm not even sure if I'm asking this right. I am currently building out a website for a client and trying to automate the processes for them. In this instance, they will be creating a folder in Google Drive which will have their client's name and some training videos for them. I have set up the automation with Zapier where when the new folder is created in Google Drive, a page is created in Wordpress with the following info: Page Title(Folder Name), Client ID (Populated using the Folder Description field), Featured Image(Client Logo).
Each client signs on for different products. We have an email that is auto-generated from the sales team that tells everyone what products were purchased including the training videos. I connected Zapier to that email and was able to pull in the list of products each client signs up for.
What I am struggling with now, is parsing that information into "custom fields" this way If a client has signed up for say products A, C and T, I only want those products to show on site, but not show all the other products.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

It sounds like you are trying to append the product info to the original created page, so all of the information is together, is that correct? Do you already have custom fields added somehow, and are now trying to get data in to them?
